# MQL query to obtain a /music/release for a /music/track

Tags: freebase, mql

If I have the `mid` for a `/music/track` entry in [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/), I can use this [MQL](https://developers.google.com/freebase/mql/ch03) query to get the releases on which that track appears:

```
{
  "mid": "/m/0q69hv",
  "name": null,
  "artist": [{
    "name": null,
    "type": "/music/artist"
  }],
  "releases": [{
    "name": null
  }],
  "type": "/music/track"
}
```

However, this depends on `/music/recording/releases` [which is deprecated](https://www.freebase.com/music/recording/releases).

How can I obtain the releases for a track without relying on the deprecated property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
{
  "mid": "/m/0p5t1p",
  "type": "/music/track",
  "name": null,
  "artist": [{
    "name": null
  }],
  "tracks": [{
    "release": {
      "name": null
    }
  }]
}
```